# File name in uploadData Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to upload a CSV to Google Analytics using the API. Everything goes OK, but file name in column shows "Unknown filename".

[image: File name is unknown]

Here is my code:

```
$analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);
try {
    $analytics->management_uploads->uploadData(
        '<acc id>',
        'UA-xxx',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ex.csv'),
            'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'uploadType' => 'media'
        )
    );

} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
    print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
        . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

} catch (apiException $e) {
    print 'There was a general API error '
        . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Is it possible to post file with flename? Thank you!

Comment: I recently had the same question and found that it is not currently possible to add the filename via the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its an issue more with the client library then the Google analytics API.

> consequence of the client libraries stripping the filename from POST body information

[Management API Cost Data Upload .csv Doesn't Have Filename](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=791&q=filename&colspec=ID%20Component%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

You can get around that by not using the client library.

```
import pycurl
import json

def curlUpload(accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId, csv):
        credential_path = 'PATHTOYOURCREDENTIALSJSONFILE'
        f = open(credential_path)
        googleAccessToken = json.loads(f.read())['access_token']

        c = pycurl.Curl()
        c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/' + accountId + '/webproperties/' + webPropertyId + '/customDataSources/' + customDataSourceId + '/uploads?access_token=' + googleAccessToken)
        c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [
        ('fileupload', (
                c.FORM_FILE, csv,
                c.FORM_CONTENTTYPE, 'application/octet-stream'
        )),
        ])
        c.perform()
        c.close()
```

Comment: Looks like something changed and now `uploads` method ignores `ContentType: multipart/form-data`, processing request as `application/octet-stream` that results in an error. I also commented on the thread you mentioned.